# Concatenate Inside of html

Tags: php, html, forms

What would be the proper way to write:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="<?php $user_id; ?>"/>
```

I can't seem to get the form to submit the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) that value:

```
<?php echo $user_id ?>
```

Additionally, when filling in HTML attributes, you should always escape the values:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_id) ?>
```

So, the proper way to output the variable would be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_id) ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>"/>`

[echo](http://php.net/echo) is used to print the value of your variable